# Negative voltage reverse protection

Tags: power-supply, protection

It's easy enough to use a P-channel MOSFET for doing positive high-side reverse voltage protection.

However, is it possible to do something similar for reverse protection for a negative voltage?

I've used just Schottky diodes in the past, but I've got a design that has a higher than normal current draw on the negative power rail which is causing hot diodes (which is not ideal, as it'll affect their life span).

Comment: I gather that a series fuse, which you probably should have anyway, and a reverse-connected parallel diode to blow the fuse is not enough? If so, then perhaps you should include more application details - at least enough to substantiate the need for series-switching solution that uses mosfets. There may well be other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse voltage protection of the negative supply line is very similar to using a P-channel MOSFET in the positive supply line. Replace the P-channel MOSFET with an N-channel MOSFET as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK1ybW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It should work with NMOS devices equivalently to using PMOS devices for reverse-polarity protection. Also a quick PSCPICE sim. delivered good results.
Hope, I could help! ;-)

[image]

[image]